# Ember-data 1.0.0.beta.9 upgrade changes load order of simple auth session data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-simple-auth

With ember-data 1.0.0-beta.8, ember-simple-auth loads the current user from my API *before* making any other requests. This guarantees the current user data will be available in other routes. After upgrading to ember-data 1.0.0-beta.9, it loads the current user *after* making other API requests.

Is there a way to force ember-simple-auth to load the current user *before* other data using ember-data 1.0.0-beta.9?

My custom simple auth session that looks like this:

```
import SimpleAuthSession from 'simple-auth/session';

export default SimpleAuthSession.extend({
  updateCurrentUser: function() {
    var self = this;
    var userId = this.get('user_id');
    if (!Ember.isEmpty(userId)) {
      self.set('currentUser', self.container.lookup('store:main').find('current-user', userId));
    }
  }.observes('user_id')
});
```

My authentication initializer:

```
import MyAppSession from 'my-app-ember/lib/my-app-session';
import FacebookAuthenticator from 'my-app-ember/lib/facebook-authenticator';

export default {
  name: 'authentication',
  before: 'simple-auth',

  initialize: function(container) {
    container.register('session:my-app-session', MyAppSession);
    container.register('simple-auth-authenticator:facebook', FacebookAuthenticator);

    window.ENV = window.ENV || {};

    window.ENV['simple-auth'] = {
      session: 'session:my-app-session',
      authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:oauth2-bearer',
      routeAfterAuthentication: 'moments'
    };

    window.ENV['simple-auth-oauth2'] = {
      serverTokenEndpoint: MyAppEmberENV.API_NAMESPACE + '/oauth/token'
    };
  }
};
```

Here's an example of a place where I'm depending on the currentUser object to be set on the session in an afterModel hook and is broken after the upgrade:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('moment');
  },

  afterModel: function() {
    if (!this.get('session.currentUser.isReturningUser')) {
      this.transitionTo('settings');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I see how that would have been working in ember data 1.0 beta 8.

Comment: @Kingpin2k It is working, but I'd be open to suggestions for how to make it better. What doesn't seem like it should work?

Comment: There's no blocking mechanism in place in that code that would force the user to be fetched beforehand.

Comment: @Kingpin2k right, that's the whole point of this post. :)

Comment: Yes, but I'm saying there wasn't one when you were using beta 8 either.

Comment: So I've been combing through the simple auth stuff, and it looks like the common pattern they are using it to hook into the application route beforeModel hook and redirecting to a login route if the user isn't authenticated.  Are you using the their application route mixin?

Comment: @Kingpin2k I'm using the application route mixin in my login controller. I've used simple-auth on a few apps and haven't hit this issue before so it seems weird that upgrading would have changed things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying every possible combination I could think of, the only thing that worked for me was to get the current user from the session in the application route. This seems pretty hacky, but I might experiment more later to see if there's something else going on.

app/routes/application.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  model: function() {
    if (this.get('session.user_id')) {
      return this.get('session.currentUser');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing something similar and don't have this issue with beta 9. I'd maybe try doing this logic in an initializer so you can run it before simple-auth init.

```
import Ember from 'ember';                               
import Session from 'simple-auth/session';               
import Authorizer from 'myapp/authorizers/custom';

export default {
  name: 'simple-auth-config',       
  before: 'simple-auth',            
  initialize: function(container) { 
    container.register('authorizer:custom', Authorizer);                                

    window.ENV = window.ENV || {};                                                      
    window.ENV['simple-auth'] = {                                                       
      authorizer: 'authorizer:custom',                                                  
      crossOriginWhitelist: [MyappENV.API_HOST]
    };                                                                                  

    window.ENV['simple-auth-oauth2'] = {                                                
      serverTokenEndpoint: MyappENV.API_HOST + '/token'                             
    };                                                                                  

    Session.reopen({                                                                    
      currentUser: function() {                                                         
        var userId = this.get('user_id');                                               
        if (!Ember.isEmpty(userId)) {                                                   
          return container.lookup('store:main').find('user', userId);                   
        }                                                                               
      }.property('user_id')                                                             
    });
  }
}
```

```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks like there are a couple differences between what you're using  and what I've got. You're using `property('user_id')` to observe the change where as I'm using `observes('user_id')`. You're also using a custom authorizer, and I'm using the simple-auth-authorizer:oauth2-bearer one. I'm going to dig around some more to see if these differences have any affect on beta.8 vs beta.9.

Comment: So doing your same logic in an initializer that runs before the simpleauth code did not fix the issue? All my custom authorizer does is set an ajax authorization header in a way Rails expects. If you weren't getting auth headers at all I would blame the authorizer, but the issue you're describing is that the find call happens after other calls. Would definitely be very strange if property vs observes was the culprit.

Comment: I'll give it a go this weekend when I have some free time.

Comment: I finally got a chance to try this and did not have any luck. I'm not sure what's going on, but posted an answer that resolved my issue. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to make sure that the user loaded successfully before any other API requests are made you'd have to add a custom initializer that defers readiness and only advances readiness after the user has successfully loaded:

```
// app/initializers/session-user.js
export default {
  name:       'session-user',       
  after:      'simple-auth',            
  initialize: function(container, application) { 
    var session = container.lookup('simple-auth-session:main');
    if (session.get('isAuthenticated')) {
      application.deferReadiness();
      session.get('currentUser').then(function() {
        application.advanceReadiness();
      }, function() {
        //handle error...
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me either. If I refresh the application while logged out, the code runs and isAuthenticated is false. When I log in, the code is not run again. I suspect it's because it's in an initializer. Do I need to bind an observer that watches the isAuthenticated property?

Comment: For the case when the session is not authenticated when the app starts and later becomes authenticated I'm not aware of any mechanism that would allow you to block all Ember Data requests until the current user has been loaded - maybe you can block the run loop somehow. But that's sth. I wouldn't suggest you actually do. You can also load the current user in the authenticator and only resolve when it loaded successfully so that the session doesn't become authenticated before.